# Unclear how to add named lifetime parameter for enum type

Tags: rust

Two semi-linked questions.

```
struct ComputeNode<'a, T: Debug + 'static> {
    value: T,
    downstream: Vec<&'a Node<T>>,
}

enum Node<T: Debug + 'static> {
    Input(InputNode<T>),
    Compute(ComputeNode<T>), //<---
}                      ~~~
```

1. Here the compiler complains that

```
missing lifetime specifier
expected named lifetime parameterrustc(E0106)
lib.rs(54, 25): expected named lifetime parameter
```

and I'm not sure how to add a lifetime to T in the ComputeNode definition?

2. Separately I couldn't find a way to make the code understand that I want T to have any references inside it have lifetime associated with the lifetime of the owning Node (not owner here but in a different place). I ended up making it 'static for now :(

Comment: For the first question, you want `ComputeNode<'static, T>`.

Comment: Hello in the first question I suggest "downstream: Vec<&'a Node<'a, T>>, "Node<'a, T: Debug + 'static>", "Compute(ComputeNode<'a, T>)"".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is: the same way you did it for `ComputeNode`, by adding a lifetime parameter to `Node`:

```
struct ComputeNode<'a, T: Debug + 'static> {
    value: T,
    downstream: Vec<&'a Node<'a, T>>,
}

enum Node<'a, T: Debug + 'static> {
    Input(InputNode<T>),
    Compute(ComputeNode<'a, T>),
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to compile - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64a7b7217b868dc5670cd613d93d18a1

Comment: @Cerberus `downstream: Vec<&'a Node<'a, T>>,`